# Query to get records with special characters only

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to write a query which will tell me if certain record is having only the special characters. e.g- "%^&%&^%&" will error however "%HH678*(*))" is fine (as it's having alphanumeric values as well. I have written following query however, it's working fine only for English alphabets and numbers, if column is having some other characters like mandarin then also it's not giving expected value.Any help is highly appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(sampletext, '[^]^A-Z^a-z^0-9^[^.^{^}^ ]' );
```

Comment: What do you expect? Do you consider Mandarin characters as "special" or not?

Comment: Only words like special characters like #@%^$ should be considered as invalid string however words like mix of special character and alphanumeric characters(including alphabets from other language) should be considered as legal.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
regexp_like(text, '^[^A-Za-z0-9]+$')
```

This would match the text only if the input text contains special chars ie, only chars which are not of letters or digits.

Comment: This can't be used for the text having non english alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

To detect strings containing only characters other than unaccented alphabetic, numeric, or white space characters try this:

```
regexp_like(text,'^[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]+$')
```

If you don't think punctuation characters are special than add `[:punct:]` to the class of characters to ignore.

If you are looking for a specific set of characters you can use a character class of just those characters of interest, for example some common  accented characters (note the lack of a leading `^` in the character class `[]`:

```
regexp_like(text,'^[àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]+$')
```